# Memory footprint of []int16 vs []int64

Tags: go

Will a slice of int16 take less RAM than int64? Or []int16 will allocate []int64 on a 64-bit machine anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slices are references to underlying *array* storage.

A slice of `int16` may only reference an array of `int16`. It may not reference an array of `int64` or any other type.

The correct question is then, does an array of `int16` have a smaller size than an array of `int64` with the same length?

In my experience in practice, **yes**. I'm not aware of any counter example. Still, I'm not aware of any language rule that actually guarantees it to be so. If you want to test it for yourself in your own environment, it is trivial to do so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof([10]int16{}))
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof([10]int64{}))
}
```

Comment: s/reference to/view into/.